# Azure Profiler Trace warns that most of the time was spent waiting - how can I tell what it is waiting for?

Tags: performance, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

In my Azure Insights - Performance View, I click on the "Profile Traces" button on the bottom right of the screen.  This opens a list of Profile Traces that have been taken, sorted by longest to shortest duration.

I click on one of the longer-running requests, and am presented with something like this:
[image]

Of course the Performance Tip Notification block catches my eye.  It's warning that over 80% of the request time was spent waiting for a resource to be available.

(The word "waiting" is a hyperlink that opens [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler) page, which is not very useful)

My question is this.  Is there any way that I can tell what resource was being waited for?

Comment: Is there some useful info in application map?

Comment: Nope...nothing.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this / found out more? I have the same question and landed here.

Comment: @JacobRastad Nope.  Turns out what I was seeing on App Insights is as good as it's gonna be able to tell me.  So I replaced App Insights with Retrace by Stackify, and their Tracked Functions feature helped me get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @ShawndeWet Could you please share more about what that "Waiting" really mapped out to once you switched tools? Same boat, it'll be a while till we can switch tools in production, so looking for clues ...

Comment: @DeepSpace101 I must apologise that I honestly don't recall what the specific scenario was in my case.  Retrace helped me find a number of different issues, and I don't remember which specific one solved the problem.